# what is the pyspark package equivalent to org.apache.spark.sql.execution?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the below code, which is in PySpark,

```py
df1 = spark.range(2, 10000000, 2)
df2 = spark.range(2, 10000000, 4)
step1 = df1.repartition(5)
step12 = df2.repartition(6)
step2 = step1.selectExpr("id * 5 as id")
step3 = step2.join(step12, ["id"])
step4 = step3.selectExpr("sum(id)")
step4.collect()
```

I want to use `step4.queryExecution.debug.codegen`, which is present in Scala package. Can anyone point me to the current package.

Answer (score 3):

This part of the API is not exposed in PySpark, but it can be reached through the internal JVM object:

```py
step4._jdf.queryExecution().debug().codegen()
```

Comment: This seems to print to stdout. Is there a way to reliably access stdout from python, or otherwise retrieve a raw string instead?